# How do i create byte array that contains 64 bits array and how do i convert those bits into hex value?

Tags: c#, byte, bit, tostring, bitarray

I want to create byte array that contains 64 bits, How can i get particular bits values say 17th bit, and also how can i get hex value of that index of byte? I did  like this, Is this correct?

```
byte[] _byte = new byte[8];
var bit17=((((_byte[2]>>1)& 0x01);
string hex=BitConverter.ToString(_byte,2,4).Replace("-", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var bits = new BitArray(64);

bool bit17 = bits[17];
```

I'm not sure what you mean by the "hex value of that bit" - it will be 0 or 1, because it's a bit.

If you have the index of a bit in a byte (between 0 and 7 inclusive) then you can convert that to a hex string as follows:

```
int bitNumber = 7; // For example.
byte value = (byte)(1 << bitNumber);
string hex = value.ToString("x");
Console.WriteLine(hex);
```

Comment: Sorry, that is hex value of index of byte

Comment: @ManjunathST Sorry, I still don't really understand what you mean by that... Can you post an example in your question?

Comment: Like Byte will be from 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 if i want hex value of index 5 means what to do?@Matthew Watson

Comment: @ManjunathST Do you mean to ask "how do I get the hex representation of a byte with a particular bit set"?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ToString()` method.

```
byte[] arr= new byte[8];
int index = 0; 
string hexValue = arr[index].ToString("X");
```